# How do I find the magnitude of these vectors?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

For a question I need to find the magnitude of these 3 vectors, can anyone give me a hand? I know it's something to do with squaring/square rooting, but I haven't managed to get the right answer

I need to find:
$||(a\cos(\theta)\sinh(u))\underline{i}+(a\sin(\theta)\cosh(u))\underline{j}||\\
||-(a\cosh(u)\sin(\theta))\underline{i}+(a\sinh(u)\cos(\theta)\underline{j}||\\
||\underline{k}||$

Comment: **hint**: For $v=a\hat{i}+b\hat{j}+c\hat{k}$, $\|v\|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$.

Comment: @AnuragA I tried that for the first one, my answer should be $a\sqrt{\sinh^2(u)+\sin^2(\theta)}$
But instead I got $a\sqrt{\cos^2(\theta)\sinh^2(u)+\sin^2(\theta)\cosh^2(u)}$

Comment: Try using the identities: $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta=1$ and $\cosh^2x-\sinh^2x=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's great that you've got to

$||(a\cos(\theta)\sinh(u))\underline{i}+(a\sin(\theta)\cosh(u))\underline{j}|| = a\sqrt{cos^2(\theta)sinh^2(u) + sin^2(\theta)cosh^2(u)}$

Then you can use the trig identity: $cosh^2u = sinh^2u + 1$ and $cos^2\theta + sin^2\theta = 1$, resulting

$||(a\cos(\theta)\sinh(u))\underline{i}+(a\sin(\theta)\cosh(u))\underline{j}|| = a\sqrt{cos^2(\theta)sinh^2(u) + sin^2(\theta)(sinh^2u + 1) } \qquad (1)$

$ = a\sqrt{[cos^2(\theta)+ sin^2(\theta)]sinh^2(u) + (sin^2(\theta))} $

$= a\sqrt{sinh^2(u) + (sin^2(\theta))} \label{eq1}$

---

Use the same trig identities to solve the second one:

$||-(a\cosh(u)\sin(\theta))\underline{i}+(a\sinh(u)\cos(\theta)\underline{j}||$

$ = a\sqrt{cosh^2(u)sin^2(\theta) + sinh^2(u)cos^2(\theta) }$

$ = a\sqrt{(sinh^2u + 1)sin^2(\theta) + sinh^2(u)cos^2(\theta) } \qquad \text{same as }(1)$

$= a\sqrt{sinh^2(u) + (sin^2(\theta))} $

---

$||\underline{k}||$ means the length of the $1 \cdot$ unit vecor in $k$ direction which equals $1$.